# Bash: piped argument to open command fails. Open commands excutes too early?

Tags: macos, bash, pipe, command-line-arguments

I'm pretty much a novice to shell scripting. I'm trying to send the output of some piped commands to an `open` command in `bash` in OSX.

My ultimate goal is to compile a Flex/Actionscript application from TextWrangler by calling a bash script with a little Applescript and have the result played directly in a Flash Player. The Applescript is pretty much doing it's job. But the bash script doesn't work as I expect. Same results when I ommit the Applescript and simply put it directly in terminal.

This is what the Applescript is sending to terminal:

```
mxmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//' | open -a 'Flash Player'
```

So basically, I read the last line of the output of `mxmlc`, which usually looks something like this:

```
/Users/fireeyedboy/Desktop/DocumentClass.swf (994 bytes)
```

and I strip everything after the first space it encounters. I know it's hardly bulletproof yet, it's still just a proof of concept. When I get this roughly working I'll refine. It returns the desired result so far:

```
/Users/fireeyedboy/Desktop/DocumentClass.swf
```

But as you can see, I then try to pipe this `sed` result to the Flash Player and that's where it fails. The Flash Player seems to open way too early. I would expect the Flash Player to open only after the script finished the `sed` command. But it opens way earlier.

So my question is twofold:

1. Is it even possible to pipe an
   argument to the open command this
   way?
2. Do I need to use some type
   of delay command to get this
   working, since the `open` command doesn't seem to be waiting for the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to give the name of the `swf` file as input to stdin of the `open` command, which it doesn't support.

It expects the file name as an argument (similar to `-a`).

You can do something like this:

```
FILENAME=`xmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//'`
open -a 'Flash Player' $FILENAME
```

or on a single line:

```
open -a 'Flash Player' `xmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//'`
```

If you're using `bash` (or another modern POSIX shell), you can replace the pretty unreadable backtick character with `$(` and `)`:

```
open -a 'Flash Player' $(xmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//')
```

Comment: It's working. I tried static_rtti's answer first. Thanks for the extra info though!

Answer (score 2):

All commands in a pipe are started at the same time. During this step, their input/outputs are chained together.

My guess is that `open -a 'Flash Player'` doesn't wait for input but simply starts the flash player. I suggest to try to run the player with an argument instead:

```
name=$(mxmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//')
open -a 'Flash Player' "$name"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the "open" command as it seems to be a mac thing, but i *think* what you want to do is:

```
open -a 'Flash Player' $(mxmlc -warnings=false DocumentClass.as | tail -n 1 | sed 's/[[:space:]].*$//')
```

In general you can't pipe arguments to a command, you have to specify that you want the output of the previous command to be treated as arguments, either as in my example or with the `xargs` command. Note that there is a limit on the maximum size of a command line, though.

Comment: Genius... It's working! Haha, o man, I'm stoked! Thanks a lot!!